# Torque due to a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

We have two infinite perpendicular wires, each carrying a current "i" and the distance between them is l.

If both the wires are free to move, how will they arrange themselves because of the torque exerted by the magnetic field produced by the two wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic force that one wire exerts on another will be uniformly distributed along the length, given the wires are parallel. Also, assuming the wires are thin, no considerable torque will be applied to cause rotation of the wire about it's axis.

Even if that torque were considerable, it would only cause the wire to spin about its axis without any change to its translational motion.

Therefore, the only considerable motion of the wires due to the interaction of the magnetic fields would be the translational motion, due to the applied force. The direction of the applied force is perpendicular to both the direction of the magnetic flux field lines, and the current of the wire the force acts upon. The flux field lines are circular around each wire, so the tangent plane of the field lines that intersect with each other wire is perpendicular to plane that connects the two wires.

This means the force acting on each wire causes the wires to be pulled together or pushed apart, depending on the directions of the currents. If the currents travel in the same direction, the lines move apart. If the currents have different directions, the wires move together.